# Salt analysis of Ag salts

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

So I was doing analysis of silver salts and I found $\ce{AgBr}$ is curry white partially soluble in ammonia, $\ce{AgI}$ is yellowish and insoluble but silver phosphate is also yellow. So can anyone tell whether or is soluble in ammonia or not?

Comment: Silver phosphate is soluble in aqueous ammonia. AgBr is only slightly soluble in ammonia. AgI is not soluble in ammonia.

Answer (score 2):

According to Firsching [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/ac60175a018)],

> silver phosphate is indeed soluble in ammoniacal solution due to formation of silver-ammonia complex.

The following is the solubility data of $\ce{Ag3PO4}$ in $\ce{NH4OH}$ at $\pu{35.5 °C}$ presented by Saraswat [[2](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03048752)]:

\begin{array}{rr}
\hline
c(\ce{NH4OH})/ & c(\ce{Ag3PO4})/ \\
\pu{mmol l^-1} & \pu{mmol l^-1} \\
\hline
0 & 0 \\
4.05 & 0.133 \\
8.09 & 0.265 \\
16.18 & 0.531 \\
32.36 & 1.061 \\
64.72 & 2.057 \\
129.45 & 4.113 \\
258.90 & 8.292 \\
517.80 & 26.478 \\
\hline
\end{array}

#### References

1. Firsching, F. H. Precipitation of Silver Phosphate from Homogenous Solution. *Anal. Chem.* **1961**, 33 (7), 873–874. DOI: [10.1021/ac60175a018](https://doi.org/10.1021/ac60175a018).
2. Saraswat, H. C. Formula of Complex Compounds from Solubility Data. *Proc. Indian Acad. Sci. (Math. Sci.)* **1949**, 30 (6), 329–332. DOI: [10.1007/BF03048752](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03048752).